# (Cartesian product) How to get the coordinate of points while each coordinate of each axis is known?

Tags: list-manipulation

For example, I have data like this:

```
 m = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}
```

It means 1,2,3 are available x position, 4,5,6 are available y position. The question is, how to get all available points? In this case, all available points are `{{1,4},{1,5},{1,6},{2,4},{2,5},{2,6},{3,4},{3,5},{3,6}}`, but how can I write a general code to solve these problems, especially when dimension is much more than 2?

I found this problem is called [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product). But I still have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: probably `Tuples`

Answer (score 6):

`Tuples` can be applied to a series of lists to give you each combination:

```
>> Tuples[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}]

{{1, 4}, {1, 5}, {1, 6}, {2, 4}, {2, 5}, {2, 6}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}, {3, 6}}
```

and it works with arbitrarily many, and different sizes of lists:

```
>> Tuples[{{y, z}, {1, 2, 5}, {7}, {9, y}}]

{{y, 1, 7, 9}, {y, 1, 7, y}, {y, 2, 7, 9}, {y, 2, 7, y}, {y, 5, 7, 9}, {y, 5, 7, y}, {z, 1, 7, 9}, {z, 1, 7, y}, {z, 2, 7, 9}, {z, 2, 7, y}, {z, 5, 7, 9}, {z, 5, 7, y}}

>> Length[%]

12 (* 2 options for first coordinate, 3 for second, 1 for third, 2 for fourth. 2*3*1*2=12 *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Outer[List, {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, 1]

(* {{{1, 4}, {1, 5}, {1, 6}}, {{2, 4}, {2, 5}, {2, 6}}, {{3, 4}, {3, 5}, {3, 6}}} *)
```